# Sleek navigation drawer

Tags: android, ios

I would like to implement a custom navigation drawer (such as the one shown here) and I have been trying all kinds of navigation menu libraries for Android and iOS but haven't come up with a good option. Is there any library that could achieve this kind of navigation or does anyone have any idea how this could be done as a custom component?

[image: Denko Navigation Drawer]

Comment: use android navigation drawer. It is the easies and the best.

Answer (score 0):

1. [First](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer)
2. [Second](https://github.com/gokhanakkurt/android-menudrawer)

Second I used before and it is nice as for me, but first one looks more promising.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). Its one of the most widely used alternatives for navigation drawer. Its gives you a whole host of options which are listed on their homepage.